# Formatting a view lotus domino designer

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Sorry for the newbie question, but....
I am wondering if it is possible to format a view by linking css to it, like it is possible for a page? 
I'd like to change the default white and black look of the view so it matches corporate identity. I have tried embedding a view into a page, but still cannot get the css to work on the embedded view =/.
The database is to be viewed locally using Lotus Notes 8.5.3, and NOT web. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS does NOT apply to "Pure" Domino Design- Elements. You define the appearance of the view directly in it's properties (Alt + Enter when the view is open in Designer), and the Properties of the selected Column.

If you display a view in Web, then you can use CSS to format it, but not in the client...